# When there are both force and gravity, what is the direction of frictional force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image: Question]

The force $F$ is to the right and the gravitational force is to the left. Then what is the direction of frictional force? Should it be opposite of gravity or acting force?

Comment: You should always start with a free body diagram (FBD). In this case, an FBD for the block

Comment: Friction is a force which opposes relative motion between two surfaces. Its direction is parallel to the surface in the case of a flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

A frictional force will always oppose motion.

If the **net** force (the resulting force when you "add" up gravity and the force that you exert) is upwards, along the ramp, i.e. the block is going up the ramp, friction will oppose this motion. The friction will be opposite to the motion, pushing it down the ramp.

On the other hand, if you are going down the ramp such that $ mgsin( \theta) > F$, the frictional force will be in the opposite direction of this motion, and will be pushing the block up the hill.

If the forces are equal so that the block doesn't move, then there is no friction force because there is no motion.

Answer (score 0):

Friction between two surfaces always acts to oppose the direction of relative motion between the surfaces that would occur if there were no friction.

In your example, the direction of friction depends on the values of the force $F$, the weight $W$ of the block and the angle $\theta$ of the slope.

If $F > W \sin \theta$ then in the absence of friction the block would move up the slope. In this case the direction of friction is down the slope.

However, if $F < W \sin \theta$ then in the absence of friction the block would move down the slope. In this case the direction of friction is up  the slope.

Comment: HI, thank you very much for answering. But can I ask one more? The solution to the problem with this diagram made this expression: to prevent the object from slipping down, ΣFx=F+fs-Wsinθ=0. I surely understand that it must be ΣFx=0, but their directions confuse me even with your explanation. F+fs-Wsinθ indicates that force F and frictional force fs are both directed to the right and the gravitational force Wsinθ is directed to the left. The part I can't understand is that F and fs have the same direction.
(continued in the following comment)

Comment: For the object to remain at rest without slipping down, the force F will have to be greater than the gravitational force Wsinθ. Then, according to your explanation, since Wsinθ<F, frictional force's direction might be directed to the left, the opposite of the net force which is to the right. But isn't what the solution is indicating by  ΣFx=F+fs-Wsinθ=0 the fact that F and fs have the same direction? Is the solution I saw wrong?

Comment: Are you assuming that the block starts from rest? Then yes, fine, but if not, then it's not generally true that $F>mg\sin\theta$ will (directly) lead to an object moving up the ramp.  It might already be moving *down* the ramp, in which case it will slow down, stop, then turn around, meaning that the kinetic friction will actually change direction during the motion. Or, it might even come to a dead stop and stay there if $|F-mg\sin\theta$ is smaller than the maximum static friction force for the two surfaces in contact

Comment: @march Yes, I am assuming that the block starts from rest.

Comment: @petitbeauté The expression $F + f_s - W \sin \theta = 0$ is derived by assuming that $f_s$ acts in the same direction as $F$ i.e. up the slope. If on substituting known values of $F, W$ and $\theta$ it turns out that $f_s$ has a negative value then this shows that $f_s$ actually acts down the slope instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Then what is the direction of frictional force? Should it be opposite
> of gravity or acting force?

There may not even be a frictional force, because frictional forces only exist in opposition to a net force that would otherwise exist without friction. It depends on the relationship between $F$ and the component of the force of gravity acting on the block down along the incline.

For example, if

$$F=mg\sin\theta$$

the net force is zero and there is no  frictional force. If

$$F\gt mg\sin\theta$$

then the frictional force would act down along the incline, opposing the net force acting up along the incline. If

$$F\lt mg\sin\theta$$

then the frictional force would act up along the incline, opposing the net force acting down along the incline.

Finally, the frictional force may be static, in which case there will be no relative motion between the block and the incline or kinetic, in which case there will be relative motion. Whether it is static or kinetic depends on whether or not the net force acting on the block exceeds the maximum possible static friction force.

The maximum possible static friction force in this example is

$$f_{s-max}=\mu_{s}mg\cos\theta$$

where $\mu_{s}$ is the coefficient of static friction between the surfaces.

We can relate the maximum static friction force to the maximum angle of incline and the coefficient of static friction. The maximum angle for maximum static friction to not be exceeded is given by

$$\tan^{-1}\theta=\mu_{s}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: "There may not even be a frictional force, because frictional forces only exist in opposition to a net force that would otherwise exist without friction." I don't agree.  Kinetic friction occurs when two objects are sliding against each other, irrespective of whatever "balancing" is done by other forces. In addition, when $F > mg \sin\theta$, the (kinetic) frictional force can be either up or down the ramp, depending on if the object is sliding down or up the ramp. Same thing for $F < ...$. What you've written is true for the case static equilibrium, and $f_{static}$ acts, but not for sliding.

Comment: @march Just to be clear, are you saying that if $F=mg\sin\theta$ there can be kinetic friction?

Comment: Yes. If those two forces cancel each other out, then the *only* possible force left is kinetic friction, and so if the object is already moving, it will continue to move but slow down due to kinetic friction.

Comment: On the other hand, *if* the initial speed is *zero* (which is not stated in the problem but *maybe* we can assume that's the case?), then what you've written is true, but for slightly different reasons, because you have to talk about the net force acting causing an acceleration. Of course, in that case, you'd have to compare $F-mg\sin\theta$ to the $f_{\textrm{static,max}}$ to see if the block starts sliding or not.

Comment: @march Slow down. First, you said  “if those two forces cancel each other out , then the only possible force left is kinetic friction”. Let’s assume that’s correct. What would be the magnitude and direction of that kinetic friction force?

Comment: In the simplest models for kinetic friction, the magnitude of $f_k$ is given by $f_k=\mu_k n$, where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction, and $n$ is the magnitude of the normal force that the ramp exerts on the block. This force necessarily opposes the sliding, and so alway points in the direction *opposite* the motion of the object relative the surface it's sliding on. This is true *irrespective* of what other forces are acting. It seems like you're trying to lead me somewhere because you disagree with something I've said.  Can you explain why you think I might be wrong?

Comment: It's possible we're just talking past each other here.  I agree with essentially everything you've said provided that the object starts from rest and either (a) remains stationary or (b) begins to move *as a consequence* of the other forces ($F$ and $mg\sin\theta$). However, the object could *already be moving* when the external force $\vec{F}$ is applied, and in that case, the kinetic friction must point in the direction opposite the direction of motion, which is independent of the direction of $\vec{F}$.

Comment: @march Since the OP made no mention of the block having been set into motion by some means, my answer was based on setting the block into motion, which of course requires a net force that exceeds the maximum possible static friction force.   But I agree if the block is already in motion then we can have kinetic friction without a net force.  That's what happens if one pushes a box on floor with friction at constant speed.  I will revise my answer to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for numerical simulation, you can use this equation

$$m\,\ddot s=F-m\,g\,\sin(\theta)+F_\mu$$

where $~F_\mu~$ is the friction force

$$F_\mu=-\mu\,m\,g\cos(\theta)\underbrace{\frac{\dot s}{|\dot s|}}_{\rm sign(\dot s)}$$

thus the direction of the friction force is allays opposite to the velocity $~\dot s~$

Answer (score 0):

There's not nearly information in the post to uniquely determine the answer. The direction of the friction force depends on a variety of factors.

Primarily, we need to know if the object is *already moving* or if it is initially stationary. This makes a difference because for *kinetic* friction, the direction of motion is not determined by the other forces acting but *purely* by the direction of slipping between the two surfaces in contact. However, the direction of *static* friction depends on the direction that the object *would* start moving if the surfaces were frictionless; in this case, then, the other forces matter, because they tell you the direction that the object *would* start moving in the absence of friction.

**Initial speed $v_i= 0$ case**

Conclusion, with details below:

If $v_i=0$, then $F>mg\sin\theta$ implies $\vec{f}_s$ points down the ramp, if $F<mg\sin\theta$ implies $\vec{f}_s$ points up the ramp, and if $F=mg\sin\theta$, the $\vec{f}_s=0$.  This is consistent with other answers posted before this one.

Details:

Let's take the simplest case first, which is that the object is initially stationary. Then, there are four forces acting on the object: gravity $\vec{F}_G$, normal force $\vec{N}$ exerted by the ramp, static friction force $\vec{f}_s$ exerted by the ramp, and the applied force $\vec{F}$. The normal force cancels the component of the gravitational force perpendicular to the ramp. In the direction parallel to the ramp, then, the net force $F_{\textrm{net, parallel}}$ (which we'll just call $F_{\textrm{net}}$) acting on the object is
$$
F_{\textrm{net}} = F - mg\sin\theta + f_s\,,
$$
where we've chosen the positive direction to be *up* the ramp, $F>0$, and $f_s$ can be positive negative or zero.

Now, *if* $F=mg\sin\theta$ *and* the initial speed is zero, then the object will remain stationary, because the static friction force would only be there due to an imbalance between these two forces. In that case, then,
$$
F=mg\sin\theta \Longrightarrow f_s=0 \Longrightarrow F_{\textrm{net}}=0\,,
$$
which implies that the object *remains* stationary.

If $F\neq mg\sin\theta$, $v_{i}=0$, *and* we observe that the object *remains stationary*, then we can conclude that the net force is zero, and so
$$
0=F_{\textrm{net}} = F - mg\sin\theta + f_s\Longrightarrow
f_s = mg\sin\theta - F\,.
$$
In this case, then, if $F<mg\sin\theta$, then $f_s>0$, and so the static friction force points *up* the ramp. That is, static friction is *helping* the applied force cancel the gravitational force.  On the other hand, if $F>mg\sin\theta$, then $f_s<0$, and so the static friction force points *down* the ramp. That is, static friction is *helping* the gravitational force cancel the applied.

Finally, if $v_i=0$ but the object is observed to *start moving* from rest, then we have to think about things slightly differently.  Since the object starts to move, this means that static friction is *broken*, in which case it must be that the difference $|F-mg\sin\theta|$ is *greater* than the maximum force $f_{s,\textrm{max}}$ that static friction can apply.

So, first, if $F>mg\sin\theta$, and the object is observed to start moving, it *must be* that the object begins to move *up the ramp*, because static friction is not strong enough to help the gravitational force match $F$. Nonetheless, at the moment *before* static friction breaks, it is points *down* the ramp to try to help the gravitational force match $F$. Similarly, if $F< mg\sin\theta$, then just before the block begins to move, static friction is pointed *up* the ramp to help $F$ cancel the gravitational force, but it's not enough, and so the object starts accelerating and moving down the ramp.  In both cases, *kinetic* friction takes over, but it points in the *same* direction as the static friction force exerted just *before* the object starts moving.

However, that's not the only possibility!

**Initial speed $v_i\neq0$**

Conclusion, with details below:

The forces $F$ and $mg\sin\theta$ tell you nothing about the direction of the kinetic friction force, because the direction of the kinetic friction force depends *purely* on the direction of sliding. So: if the object slides down the ramp, kinetic friction points up the ramp, and vice versa.  The other forces *will* tell you if the object slows down, speeds up, or moves at a constant speed going forward in time.

Details:

We won't consider both cases here, because the alternative has the same line of reasoning, so let's consider the case where initially, the object is sliding *down* the ramp. In this case, the kinetic friction force that is applied is *necessarily* pointed *up* the ramp, because kinetic friction opposes the sliding. Now, at this moment, supposed $\vec{F}$ is applied to the object and continues to be exerted on the object. Then, *no matter how* $F$ compares to $mg\sin\theta$, the kinetic friction force still points up the ramp.

In the case where $F>mg\sin\theta$, we have
$$
F_{\textrm{net}} = F - mg\sin\theta + f_k\,,
$$
where $f_k>0$, because it points *up* the ramp. Then, $F_{\textrm{net}}>0$, and so the object will slow down because it is moving *down* the ramp but with a net force pointed *up* the ramp.

In the case where $F<mg\sin\theta$, we have, again,
$$
F_{\textrm{net}} = F - mg\sin\theta + f_k\,.
$$
If $F = mg\sin\theta - f_k$, then the net force is zero, and the object slides down the ramp at constant speed.  If $F$ is *smaller, then the net force points down the ramp, and so the object speeds up (just with a smaller acceleration then if *just* friction was acting).  Finally, if $F$ is *larger*, then the net force points *up* the ramp, and so the object will slow down as it moves down the ramp.

Comment: The component of the total force between surfaces in the direction normal to the surface can be absorbed into the definition of the normal reaction force. It does not need to be called static friction, though I guess you could call it static friction of a kind.

Comment: @AndrewSteane It's pretty standard at the apparent level of the OP's problem to call the force acting parallel to the two surfaces in contact (when they're not sliding along each other) static friction.  Perhaps there's something funny in the logic of my analysis here, but I *think* everything I've said makes sense.